# Should I use .w-100 or .row to make a table-like Grid design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a `table` strcuture using bootstrap grids, and i was wondering which one of the following structure is the best and correct semantically.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or should i go this structure

```css
.w-100 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class='col'>A</div>
    <div class='col'>B</div>
    <div class='col'>C</div>
    <div class='col'>D</div>
    <div class='col'>E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand from my two designs that the first one is a lot easier to be styled, but the second one is really simplistic and hard to be designed, But is that all about it?

Comment: tabular data should semantically be in a table is there a reason why you are recreating a table as divs?

Comment: I'm trying to make a page that has some similarities to `<table>` tag, But some parts of it doesn't fit in the `<table>` tag design, So i'm trying to make mine.

Comment: You are trying to create a grid, not a table. So let's call it a grid cause that's what it is.

Comment: @Rob I see, a Grid like a Table, Updated to fit with it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both structures are good but I would suggest that you go with the first one. In the second one when you add the .w-100, you'd have to mix in some responsive utilities as it says in the bootstrap documentation to make the multi-row columns responsive.

> Create equal-width columns that span multiple rows by inserting a .w-100 where you want the columns to break to a new line. Make the breaks responsive by mixing the .w-100 with some responsive display utilities.

You can find the responsive display utilities [here.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/)

Bear in mind that in the first structure, you are just creating different rows, each with equal width columns, however in the second one, you are creating equal width multi-row columns by using the .w-100 class. For further clarification, read the bootstrap docs or the source CSS code.

Important: I would suggest you don't use either of these methods, but use the table classes provided in bootstrap. They are there for a reason.